# Structured Query Language ( SQL)

Tags: sql

I have tried the following query, but it doesn't give me an required data.
I want the data between two dates including both the mentioned dates.

```
SELECT
    column names
FROM
    table name
WHERE
    date >= DATE('10/01/2013','mm/dd/yyyy')
    AND
    date <= DATE('10/21/2013','mm/dd/yyyy')
```

Comment: What does it give you? Perhaps some sample data and actual vs expected results would help?

Comment: what DB do you use? mySQL? Oracle? MS-SQL?

Comment: Please change the title of the question. This one is totally useless for further searchess

Comment: Since we have a tag system for marking the technologies of interest (e.g. sql, and as other have said, you ought to also include the specific RDBMS), it makes you title meaningless. Could you not think of anything to say about date ranges?

Comment: if that `date` column actually includes a time component as well, it's almost always better to switch to using semi-open intervals - an inclusive start date/time and an *exclusive* end date/time.

Answer (score 1):

Date('10/21/2013') might be interpreted as 10/21/2013 00:00am by some RDBMS. If that's the case your query won't return anything beyond that. To include the last day you will have to use the date of the following day. i.e. 10/22/2013

Comment: Yes, the query that i am using giving me data between 10/01/2013 to 10/20/2013, not giving the data of 10/21/2013

Answer (score 0):

I assuce your `date` column is really a `datetime`. You can compare with `< next day` to set the end range:

```
select col1 
from your_table
where date_column >= '2013-10-01' 
and date_column < '2013-10-22'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select column_names 
from table_name 
where date >= '2013-10-01' and date<= '2013-10-21'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @StartDate date = '10/01/2013'
declare @EndDate date = '10/21/2013'

select * from your_table where date >= @StartDate and date < @EndDate
```